# Nuxt - getter for window innerwidth does not update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Our project uses class based components. I have a getter to get the window innerWidth, but the value is only set once, it doesn't update if I change the window width.

```
get viewPortWidth() {
  
    if (process.client) {
          if (window.innerWidth !== undefined && window.innerHeight !== undefined) {
            return window.innerWidth;
          } else {
            return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
          }
        }
        return false; 
  }
```

If I write the value in the html: `{{viewPortWidth}}` it doesn't change.
The value is the same also in vue devtools.
Aren't getters supposed work like computed properties? How can I get to update seamlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vue computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies.
window.innerWidth not a reactive dependency.

you can track changing window size event by adding an event listener in your "created" lifecycle hook like this:

```
created(){window.addEventListener('resize', (e)=>{console.log(e)})}
```